# Plotting specific shapes from an array

Tags: pine-script

I am creating an indicator from data that is not available from a trading view and I want to learn how to plot it from a manually defined array.

My indicator is based on circles that vary in size and appear every hour (there could be no circles at certain places). The data is not available for all time and it starts mid-2020.

My question is: How do I plot a number of circles only at specific bars using pinescript. Say I have an array that indicates if there should be no circle (0), a small one (1), medium one (2) and a big one (3).

```
[0,2,3,3,3,1]
```

Also, as I understand that pinescript cannot retrieve data from API (only make API calls), so I will have to write a bot that manually edits the array.